Short Film. Seems to be religous cult committting mass suicide. Then we discover they killed themselves because a disaster is about to kill everyone
It was about 30 minutes long. I watched it in 2023 or 2024. It was recently made and had high production values.It is set in modern day rural America.
Several families gather in a large house preparing food. A  child tries to eat a cake his dad pushes his hand away and tells him it is for later.
A teenage couple and the younger brother of the girl are served a wonderful feast in a bedroom. The teenagers whisper to the younger kid warning him not to eat the food. They hide their own food. The mother of the teenage girl says when you wake up you will be in heaven.
The little boy eats some food and dies from poison. The teenage couple get up and go downstairs. Everyone downstairs is also dead from tbe poisoned food.
The viewer thinks it is a crazy suicide cult. The teenagers talk about there being a shelter in town.
They take a large white car and drive to town. The radio decribes a disaster and its current geographical location. It is approaching their town. It has an ominous name but the nature of the deadly disaster is not explained. The teenagers say they will have to stay sealed in the shelter for a long time to survive but there is lots of food stored there.
In town they find a group of naked tatooed people having sex and getting drunk and smoking weed. The teenagers are a bit shocked. An older naked man is listening to music on headphones. The teenage girl nervously approaches him and says "Excuse me, where's the shelter please?" he gently replies "What shelter?" The teenagers run away. They stop in a forest and make love, then

the disaster catches up with them and they die.


https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbidden_Fruit_(American_Horror_Story)?

@Valorum Thanks. That definitely isn't it. Though it has a similar theme. There were no demons or nuclear wasteland in the show I watched.

Was the disaster sci-fi or fantasy?

Scifi I am pretty sure. I saw no fantasy aspects.
